# Virtual Keyboard Borderless Win 10

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard, virtual, borderless

I'm trying to put the Virtual Keyboard of Win 10 Borderless
But don't know why it's not working.

I tried with NotePad and it's working.

( I did a Debug.log to check if IntPtr is not null and in both case it return true)

Here's what I did

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class test : MonoBehaviour 
{
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);

const int WS_BORDER = 8388608;
const int WS_DLGFRAME = 4194304;
const int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME;
const int WS_SYSMENU = 524288;
const int WS_THICKFRAME = 262144;
const int WS_MINIMIZE = 536870912;
const int WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 65536;
const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x1;
const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x20;
const uint MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;
const uint MF_REMOVE = 0x1000;

private void Borderless() {

   // IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null,"On-Screen Keyboard"); // <----- Not Working
    IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null,"Untitled - NotePad"); // <----- Working

    if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) 
    {
        int Style = 0;

        Style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
        Style = Style & ~WS_CAPTION;
        Style = Style & ~WS_SYSMENU;
        Style = Style & ~WS_THICKFRAME;
        Style = Style & ~WS_MINIMIZE;
        Style = Style & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX;

        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, Style);
        Style = GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, Style | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, new IntPtr(0), 50, 0, 150, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }
     else 
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Borderless() failed, hWnd is 0!");
    }
}

void Start()
{
    Borderless();
}
```

}

Thanks Guys ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I get another Solution, Maybe a better one.

[On-Screen Keyboard on Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1134775/on-screen-keyboard-pc-and-console-best-practices.html)

I know it's not a real answer so if someone know why the code above is not working, I'll be glad to learn ;)